# pytest assert multiple objects in single line

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, assert, equality

I am using pytest to assert multiple objects for same condition.
Board of writing repetitive code. I wanted to know how these multiple objects can be clubbed together to test at once in a single line.

Below is my current code:

```
assert response['a'] is not None
assert response['b'] is not None
assert response['c'] is not None
assert response['d'] is not None
```

Essentially what I am looking for is something like this:
`assert response['a'], response['b'], response['c'], response['d'] is not None`

I did study about parametrixing fixtures but looks like that is not for my current use case.

Comment: `for param in ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'): assert response[param] is not None` perhaps.

Comment: `for param in "abcd": assert response.get(param) is not None` as an alternative. Note that writing this in two lines is considered more _Pythonic_.

Answer (score 1):

```py
assert all(getattr(response, x) for x in ["a", "b", "c", "d"])
```

Answer (score 0):

For identical tests, the parametrize decorator of pytest allows you to write a single test changing parameter(s).

The code readability is improved compared to a list comprehension because the test is simpler. More over your Junit or report is split into a single test for each attribute which highlights where the issue is:

[image]

Another issue is that testing the key is not `None` wil raise a `KeyError` if the key is absent and your test status will be **error**, not **failed**. Use the `get` method on the object to get None if the is absent.

Therefore I would write the test this way (assuming `response` can be a fixture):

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture()
def response():
    return {"a": 1, "b": None}

@pytest.mark.parametrize("attribute", ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'))
def test_attributes(attribute, response):
    assert response.get(attribute) is not None
```